# Swift & json : Array of objects

Tags: json, swift

I have a json file of the format :

```
{
    "houses": [
        {
            "description": "House 1",
            "surface": "500"
        },

        {
            "description": "House 2",
            "surface": "200"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to fetch these data and be able to manipulate the inner data only (without the word houses).
Here is a part of my request where I get stuck

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

    if let result = jsonResult as? [String : Any] {

        var housesArray: [String:Any] = ["":""]
        result = ["houses":housesArray]


        print(housesArray)

    }
```

but my housesArray is always empty. How can proceed please ? Thank you

Comment: What about using `Codable`, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (kind of) *writing* to the result but you need to *read* from the result

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
   let housesArray = jsonResult["houses"] as? [[String:String]] {
      print(housesArray)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be

```
if let result = jsonResult as? [String : Any] {

   if let housesArray = result["houses"] as? [[String:Any]] {
         print(housesArray)
    }

}
```

Now check.

Answer (score 1):

[QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io?share=BSmcLao2B7KCaa3k80ca) will write the decoder for you:

```
struct Houses: Codable {
    var houses: [House]
}

struct House: Codable {
    var houseDescription, surface: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case houseDescription = "description"
        case surface
    }
}
```

Then decode and extract `.houses`:

```
let houses = try JSONDecoder().decode(Houses.self, from: jsonData).houses
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check it ^^